# Atomic variables vs synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, atomic

I have a counter class which has increment and decrement method, both the methods are synchronized.

```
public class Counter {
   int count = 0;
   public synchronized void increment(){
       count++;
   }

   public synchronized void decrement(){
       count--;
   }
}
```

Its very clear from this example that race condition won't happen, only one thread can access increment or decrement method.

Now instead of integer primitives, if I modified the counter class with Atomic Integer and removed the synchronized keyword, can we achieve the same thing ?

```
public class Counter {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    public void increment(){
       count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void decrement(){
       count.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Starting with `java-8` there is a *better* (read faster in really contended environments) option instead of `AtomicInteger`, it's called [`LongAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) and it guarantees atomic updates in the same manner:

> Under low update contention, the two classes have similar
>    characteristics (AtomicLong). But under high contention, expected throughput of
>    this class is significantly higher, at the expense of higher space
>    consumption.

Its implementation is superb. In plain english (simplified): if there is no contention between threads, don’t be a smart ass and simply work as with AtomicLong; if there is, try to create a separate working space for each thread, so that contention is minimized.

It has the same methods you care about: `add` and `decrement`.

Comment: Contention means competition for resources. The term is used especially in networks to describe the situation where two or more nodes attempt to transmit a message across the same wire at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Well, this is the kind of question where you could write a quick 'n' dirty program to evaluate:

```
public class ThreadExperiment {

    public static class CounterSync {
        int count = 0;
        public synchronized void increment(){
            count++;
        }

        public synchronized void decrement(){
            count--;
        }
    }

    public static class CounterAtomic {
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

        public  void increment(){
            count.incrementAndGet();
        }

        public void decrement(){
            count.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final CounterSync counterSync = new CounterSync();
        final CounterAtomic counterAtomic = new CounterAtomic();

        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                int j = i & 1;
                if (j == 0) {
                    counterSync.increment();
                    counterAtomic.increment();
                } else {
                    counterSync.decrement();
                    counterAtomic.decrement();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(runnable);
        }

        for (Thread t : threads)
            t.start();

        for (Thread t : threads)
            t.join();

        System.out.println("Sync count = " + counterSync.count);
        System.out.println("Atomic count = " + counterAtomic.count.intValue());
    }
}
```

In the end, both counters should and will be 0. By removing the "synchronized" keywords, you will see that things go completely wrong.

So yes, both achieve the same thing: thread safeness.

Oracle documents the example here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

> For this simple class, synchronization is an acceptable solution. But for a more complicated class, we might want to avoid the liveness impact of unnecessary synchronization. Replacing the int field with an AtomicInteger allows us to prevent thread interference without resorting to synchronization

In the end, the behaviour of your methods will make the difference if you need explicit synchronization or if atomic fields will be enough.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my question is in which use cases we can use Atomic variables and when we can use "synchronized"

Comment: Well, perfer atomic over synchronized whenever you can. Synchronizing methods has a wide(r) "locking" effect.  I recommend reading the following link and all its sub pages: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: @MarcusK. a small example is not proof of anything - except that it works under the current environment for the actual run. a correct way to prove this is by documentation ONLY

Comment: OK, that might be too general. Think about a class with 5 methods or so. And they do quite complex (time consuming) stuff. If you synchronize every method, then only one thread per time can call a method on your object, even if other threads call other methods. The synchronized lock locks the whole object, not just the field within your class you want to synchronize. By using Atomic___, all threads can access your object at the same time. - You need to think hard if your application code will correctly work unter this condition. If not, better be restrictive and synchronize.

Comment: @Eugene For sure this is not a proof. Even documentation sometimes is not a proof, as implementation details might change or race conditions were not taken into account. For the given question, I think that this example is good enough to show the effect, at least if you remove the synchronized keywords. But feel free to make a better anwer including links to the related Java spec :-)

Comment: @MarcusK. in this case you could have made it a lot simpler I guess:  `AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
        IntStream.range(0, 100_000_000)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(x -> ai.incrementAndGet()); System.out.println(ai.get() == 100_000_000);`

Comment: @Eugene assuming you want to show that AtomicInteger works and at least Java 8 is in use, yes, you're right. That's why I started with "quick 'n' dirty" so even new programmers can try out, without having deep knowledge of the elegant but complex Streaming API.

Comment: Doesn't `CounterSync.count` needs to be atomic? If not the `increment` method can be called from threads in different processors and the `counter` value my be cached in the processor's cache.